# Where is the Device selector in new ADT when creating new AVD?

Tags: android, adt, googleio

I've just watched the [Google I/O 2012 - What's New in Android Developers' Tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ&feature=player_detailpage#t=347s) video (the link should point at what I'm talking about, around 6th minute) and I was wondering why I can not find the Device selector when creating a new *Android Virtual Device* in *AVD Manager*... isn't it yet implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of ADT 20.0.1 this is not yet released.

In the other answer to this question, targets and devices are confused. You can install additional targets, but you still you need to manually configure the device specific properties when creating a new emulator.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is implemented:
[image: Android SDK Manager]

You can install device template, like Droid4 (there are a lot of templates, you can find some on vendors' sites too)

Comment: So I should search for some Android SDK Manager add-on sites that provides some templates, like Nexus 7?